# Can I create Multiple forms assigned to multiple views for the same Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, list-view, custom-list, edit-form

I have a requirement where I need to render multiple views of the same list across my site collection, which is rather straightforward.

However is it possible for me to create multiple forms (content types?) and assign them accordingly to the various views?

Essentially I'd like certain users of certain views to view all of the information in the list but only be able to edit certain fields made available to them via the form.

First, is this possible and if so what would be a good strategy in going about it.

Environment: SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily assign content types/forms to views.

But you can go the other way of creating multiple content types for your list and then create views which filter based on the content types.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but couldn't I just hide certain content type forms (while dropping down on New Item Ribbon Button) on my other views?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple forms (new, edit and view forms) based on content types and set them as default.
So if your list has lets say two content types 'ContentTypeA' and 'ContentTypeB', you can open default forms for them which will have only those columns which are present in respective content types.
After that you can create separate views in which you have to manually add only those columns which are present in that particular content type. But if content type changes view has to be changed manually.
Hope that helps.